# jQuery/Javascript split a text node into two or three?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div let's say with 3 lines of text. I want to split that div into two, so let's say I have 150 characters, I want to split it so I would end up with two equal parts by word.

So let me explain a bit more:

A text node is below... It has 6 lines in the stackoverflow wysiwyg container:

```
<p>Brown the roast on all sides in a large lightly oiled skillet over high heat, before 
adding to the slow cooker. While meat is browning. Prepare vegetables by washing and paring 
potatoes, carrots, and parsnips. Cut into pieces, approximately 2 inches (5 cm) in length. 
Place in the bottom, and up the sides, of a slow cooker. Add onions, and place pot roast on 
top. Combine cranberry sauce, orange juice, rind and cinnamon and pour over the meat. Cover 
and cook on low for 8-10 hours. Yield: 6 servings.</p>
```

Let's say I want to split that div into two divs of 52 pixels (according to my browser it is 104 pixels height). But I want to do it so it doesn't mean up the wording, meaning I don't want to split`Cut` into two words, so `C` in one div and `ut` in another, for example.

So I would end up with something like

Div 1

```
<p>Brown the roast on all sides in a large lightly oiled skillet over high heat, before 
    adding to the slow cooker. While meat is browning. Prepare vegetables by washing and paring 
    potatoes, carrots, and parsnips. Cut into pieces, approximately 2 inches (5 cm) in length. </p>
```

Div 2

```
<p>Place in the bottom, and up the sides, of a slow cooker. Add onions, and place pot roast on 
    top. Combine cranberry sauce, orange juice, rind and cinnamon and pour over the meat. Cover 
    and cook on low for 8-10 hours. Yield: 6 servings.</p>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would `.split()` the string on periods, assuming that would divide the block of text into sentences, and then recombine several sentences into smaller paragraphs. However, there's no way to know without reading the text what the best, most grammatical way is to do that. This is something that just can't be done by computers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
var text = $('div').text();
var tokens = text.split(' ');
var n = Math.floor(tokens.length/2);
var html = '<p>'+tokens.slice(0, n).join(' ') + '</p><p>' + tokens.slice(n+1, tokens.length).join(' ') + '</p>';
$('div').html(html);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/uPtfA/)

Note that for a better result, especially regarding a recipe, you could also split on the dot :

```
var text = $('#a').text();
var tokens = text.split('.');
var n = Math.floor(tokens.length/2);
var html = '<p>'+tokens.slice(0, n).join('.') + '.</p><p>' + tokens.slice(n+1, tokens.length).join('.') + '</p>';
$('#a').html(html);​
```

[Demonstration with a split on the dot](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/uPtfA/)

Now, it's probable you don't want to have the same number of sentences in both paragraph but about the same length in characters. Then, here's what you can do :

```
var text = $('#a').text();
var sentences = text.split('.');
var sum = 0;
var lengths = sentences.map(function(v){sum+=v.length; return v.length});
var n = 0;
var ts = 0;
while (ts<sum/2) ts += lengths[n++];
var html = '<p>'+sentences.slice(0, n-1).join('.') + '.</p><p>' + sentences.slice(n, sentences.length).join('.') + '</p>';
$('#a').html(html);
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/paracut.html) (not on jsfiddle.net because they seem to be down)

Comment: First implementations ends up skipping a word in some cases. Following change fixes it: tokens.slice(0, n).join(' ') for first and tokens.slice(n, tokens.length).join(' ') for the second